# PowerMockito.spy breaks test when used for verify

Tags: java, junit, mockito, netty, powermockito

I have a unit test (simplified version below) that tests a Netty handler.

1. I create an [EmbeddedChannel](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/embedded/EmbeddedChannel.html) with an instance of the handler.
2. The caller writes a string to the channel
3. The handler receives the string, reverses and writes it back.
4. The caller reads the return values from the channel and verifies it is the reverse of the sent string.

This works perfectly. However, I need to [verify](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.1/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verify(T,%20org.mockito.verification.VerificationMode)) the number of invocations on the channel, so I created  a [spy](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.1/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy(T)) of the channel but mocked no methods, since I don't want to change the behavior of the class, just count invocations.

Now the test fails. 2 of the assertions succeed. They are a test to make sure the handler was called, and a test to verify the number of times a method of the channel was called. However, the final read response is always null when the spy is used.

I was under the impression that a solitary spy with no other mocking would not affect the behavior of the spied object, but obviously it does. The [nonPower] Mockito docs indicate the objects are copied which might cause this issue, but the PowerMockito docs are not as specific.

I am using Netty 4.1.6.Final and Powermock 1.5.6.

**UPDATE**: I managed to get the test working but it's a bit of wonky workaround. See the new method ***testSpiedEmbeddedChannel2***. The workaround is that I create a non-spied channel (**ecx**), then a the spied channel (**ec**) using **ecx**. I issued the write on **ec**, and the read using **ecx**. This means if I try to verify methods used in the read, they will not be counted.

Here's the code with the successful and failing tests.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*"})
@PrepareForTest(EmbeddedChannel.class)
public class TestEmbeddedChannel {

    class EchoHandler extends ChannelDuplexHandler {
        final AtomicInteger reads = new AtomicInteger(0);
        @Override
        public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final Object msg) throws Exception {
            reads.incrementAndGet();
            final String value = (String)msg;
            final String response = new StringBuilder(value).reverse().toString();
            ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(response);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testEmbeddedChannel() {  // PASSES
        final EchoHandler handler = new EchoHandler();
        final EmbeddedChannel ec = new EmbeddedChannel(handler);
        ec.writeInbound("Hello World");
        final String response = ec.readOutbound();      
        Assert.assertEquals(1, handler.reads.get());
        Assert.assertEquals("dlroW olleH", response);

    }

    @Test
    public void testSpiedEmbeddedChannel() {  // FAILS
        final EchoHandler handler = new EchoHandler();
        final EmbeddedChannel ec = spy(new EmbeddedChannel(handler));
        ec.writeInbound("Hello World");
        final String response = ec.readOutbound();
        verify(ec, times(2)).isOpen();  // OK
        Assert.assertEquals(1, handler.reads.get());  // OK
        Assert.assertEquals("dlroW olleH", response);  // FAILS
    }

    @Test
    public void testSpiedEmbeddedChannel2() {  // PASSES
        final EchoHandler handler = new EchoHandler();
        final EmbeddedChannel ecx = new EmbeddedChannel(handler); 
        final EmbeddedChannel ec = spy(ecx);
        ec.writeInbound("Hello World");
        final String response = ecx.readOutbound(); // Read using non-spied channel
        verify(ec, times(2)).isOpen();
        Assert.assertEquals(1, handler.reads.get());
        Assert.assertEquals("dlroW olleH", response);
    }   

}
```

Thanks for any guidance here.

Comment: Look likes it PowerMock bug. Could you create a new issue on GitHub?

Comment: Done. Thanks.  https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/747